# Which is the most well-known Esperanto movie?

Tags: culture

From [La Sturmo de Johana Arimo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Arima_no_sh%C5%ABgeki) to the animated short Cxapeloj, there are actually quite a few Esperanto [movies](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-filmo) out there. Which is the most well-known / most watched in Esperantujo? Would that be Gerda Malaperis? (Simply because it's the only one I have seen so far, I think.)
I guess criteria could be YouTube views or public displays at congresses where an estimated number of viewers is known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would **certainly** be *Incubus* (1966) starring William Shatner. No Esperanto movie has reached anywhere near its fame. After this, I would venture that either the films of Christopher Mihm like *Atako de la lunaj zombioj* (although some would disqualify this, since it's an English movie dubbed into Esperanto) or *Gerda Malaperis*. Unfortunately sales statistics for none of these films are public, so past Incubus, it is very difficult to guess what the second most popular Esperanto film would be.

Comment: Most (in)famous, probably yes. But could it really be the most well-known (in the sense of most watched) one? [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Incubus_(1966_film)&oldid=1039663683#Release) it was released to theaters _only_ in France and considered lost for quite some time afterwards. Have DVD sales made up for that since then?

Answer (score 3):

Incubus is pretty much the only full length Esperanto movie so it wins by default. However, I'd say it's infamous due to the terrible Esperanto used.